# Сортировка и вывод массива

Tags: c#

Я решаю следующую задачу

> Дана вещественная матрица размером MxN. Упорядочить ее строки по неубыванию суммы их элементов.

Вот мой алгоритм

1. создаем массив и рандомно его заполняем,
2. создаем массив еще один, в котором i-ый элемент равен сумме i-ой строки,
3. сортируем второй массив по возрастанию,
4. выводим строки первого массива в том порядке, в котором отсортированы элементы второго массива.

Вот как я делаю два первых пункта, а остальное - пока не знаю и у меня второй пункт нормально не выполняется.

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество строк матрицы");
int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество столбцов матрицы");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] arr = new int[m, n];
int[] sum = new int[n];
Random row = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        arr[i, j] = row.Next(800);
        Console.Write(arr[i, j] + "t");
        sum[i] += arr[i, j];
        Console.Write(sum[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** решение не оптимальное, вся оптимизация на вашей совести

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> subList;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    subList = new List<int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        arr[i, j] = row.Next(10);
        subList.Add(arr[i,j]);
    }
    list.Add(subList);
}
=========
4 0 9 6 4 
1 4 9 5 2 
8 0 8 7 9 
2 5 9 0 1 
7 8 4 7 1 
=========
int idx=0;
foreach(var lst in list.OrderBy(lst=>lst.Sum()))
{
    int j=0;
    foreach(var l in lst)
    {
        arr[idx,j]=l;
            Console.Write(arr[idx,j]);
        j++;
    }
    idx++;
    Console.WriteLine();
}
=========
2 5 9 0 1 
1 4 9 5 2 
4 0 9 6 4 
7 8 4 7 1 
8 0 8 7 9 
=========
```

Comment: первая создаёт список списков, вторая возвращает списки из списка, отсортировав их согласно указоному предикату, в данном случае по сумме элементов списка

Comment: и где в коде надо прописать  вывод промежуточных результатов?

Comment: как вы делали в циклах for, так же в циклах foreach

Comment: сделал но он мне не выдает не исходный массив ни сортированный а просто программу завершает !

Comment: прислушайтесь к совету тов. @mikillskegg про чтение учебников, я обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

В п. 2 создаем не массив значений сумм строк, а массив объектов или структур с 2 полями, одно из которых - сумма строки, другое - ссылка на строку. Вот этот массив и сортируем по первому полю.

Comment: Ну я еще такого не знаю как реализовать

Comment: Тогда берем учебник и читаем, читаем, читаем.

Comment: а помочь не можете?

Comment: Я С#  не знаю, на С, С++ - пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо! С++ уже темное прошлое. На нем могу.

Comment: Если можете на C++, то на C# тоже не должно вызывать проблем, работа с массивами для реализации данного задания одинакова(если не использовать "премудрости" как в примере выше).

Comment: вот как разтаки у меня проблемы! сейчас в принцепи дописал все работает!